# Locking in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, locking, deadlock

[image]

If a stored procedure has multiple statements, will the lock acquired for the first statement be released once its executed or will it hold on till entire stored procedure is complete?

I am running a stored procedure under transaction from Entity Framework. Invoking the same stored procedure multiple times simultaneously is causing deadlock. The stored procedure selects a bunch of records from a table and inserts back into same table and moves on to next table. For some tables, it makes join with previous table to get the list of records to be inserted.

The stored procedure doesn't have any transaction but the call from application routed via Entity Framework has a transaction

Comment: Many variables.  Does the procedure have a BEGIN TRAN?  Is it called from code that begins a transaction?  What Isolation Level are you using?

Comment: You should post the deadlock graph XML - that will help us to help you. I agree that there are many possibilities and without looking at the deadlock xml, we cant help you much.

Comment: Are you using entity framework to wrap the call to the SP in a transaction? You might want to handle the transactions in the SP to get a more granular level of transaction handling. We really need to see the code though

Comment: @Kin Updated the question with deadlock graph

Comment: @JamesAnderson: Yes the EF call has a transaction for the call. The index in graph above is foreign key constraint index.

Comment: Like kin said the xml of the deadlock graph would help a lot.

Comment: What version of EF are you using?  I believe the default Isolation Level of an EF 4.0 transaction is Serializable, which would certainly have an impact here.

Comment: I've seen this happen due to lock escalation (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx) -- your sproc gets a read lock and then tries to escalate that to a write lock. Simultaneous calls may both get the read lock and then fail to get the write lock because both are holding a read lock. One way to get past this is to add a lock hint (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189857(v=sql.105).aspx) that immediately tries to get a write lock.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of this is that, yes, under a transaction your SP will hold locks for the duration of the transaction. (Note there are lots of types of locks - SQL Server could row lock, table lock, page lock etc)

One SP being called simultaneously (with no other activity on your DB) causing deadlocks suggests one thing to me: the SP is not locking the same things in the same order on each call. Do you have IF blocks that perform actions on a table if a condition is met? You may wish to rewrite those to make the IF condition appear in the WHERE condition instead. This will ensure the SP locks the same resources in the same order each time.